# replace component with its content - angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am looking for a way to have a component that is rendered only with its content. For example, Given the component:

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: '<div> my-cmp </div>'})
class MyComponent {
}
```

rendering it with angular2 will add the following to the DOM:

```
<my-cmp>
    <div> my-cmp </div>
</my-cmp>
```

While I want to find a way to render it directly as:

```
<div> my-cmp </div>
```

Sadly since angular 2 is relatively new (just went beta) - Google is not so helpful, not to mention how lacking the current documentation is..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) of angular 1.x

> Replace the directive's element itself (if replace is true -
>   DEPRECATED).

So i think this feature won't be available it angular 2

Answer (score 15):

Sort of the same can be achieved by using an attribute selector

camelCasing is mandatory for attributes since [alpha.52](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-alpha52-2015-12-10)

```
@Component({
     selector: '[myCmp]', //attribute selector
     template: 'my-cmp'
})
class MyComponent {
}
```

And use this to call it:

```
<div myCmp></div>
```

Comment: this makes my markup ugly, as the tag and classes for the component are no longer a concern of the component.. :-(

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli you're right... I want to write a "custom" component tag name instead of html markup... :P

Answer (score 3):

You can do somethink like the following:

```
@Component({selector: 'div.my-cmp', template: 'my-cmp'})
class MyComponent {
}
```

and in your HTML:

```
 <div class="my-cmp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember asking a similar question for Angularjs a few years ago. The concensus seemed to be then, as it is might be now is you *probably* don't want to do that.

It breaks semantics: a `<video/>` or a `<input/>` does not decompose into its contents. Your Angular components should not either.

You can probably still achieve what you want by thinking more deeply about your markup/css? Perhaps if you flesh out your use case we might be able to give you an alternative?